# First time Rancid (cisco)

Tags: cisco, rancid

is my first time using Rancid.

-How can I set it up to get only a "show run"
-How can I set it to add a "write" just before the "show run"
-Which file is correct for editing this

thx!

Comment: Does this ["Getting Started with Rancid"](https://networklore.com/rancid-getting-started/) help you?

Comment: Hey Ron, thanks for answering. Rancid right now I've got it working. When running it generates the file but a lot of data comes out that I don't want, I would just like to have a "sh run". The problem is that I looked at the scripts you have in /bin but I can't find where the commands you run are